# How to make LoadingComponent center when I open/close side menu bar with position:fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a loading component with the following CSS:

```
.loadingContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Now, there is a menu bar on the left side, **I need to position this loading component at the centre of the content screen** (Content screen: The area excluding menu bar content. So, If the menu bar is opened then the content screen is reduced and if the menu bar is the closed content screen is full screen).

Can't do with Position as absolute because the component is getting disappeared, also by setting position as absolute, it is set to the nearest relative positioned parent, and here in certain cases that parent will be disappeared (based on data and which is by design), so it's causing loading component also disappear.

Is there a way to do this with only position as fixed?

Comment: I think you can use `transform` css property. e.g) `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` check out https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_transform

Answer (score 0):

You might try flexbox to center the loading element:

```css
#content-screen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

However, it'll center everything inside the content container, so it might not be the best solution for you.

If you want the `.loadingContainer` to be `position: fixed;`, then try the following solution:

```css
#loading-screen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-bar"></div>
<div id="content-screen"></div>
<div id="loading-screen">
  <div class="loadingContainer"</div>
</div>
```

In this case, you're creating a `#loading-screen` element, which fits to the exact size of the screen, and has a `display: flex;`. With the properties `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;`, the `.loadingContainer` element will be perfectly centered and its position will be fixed as its parent's position. You can resize the `#loading-screen` whenever you want and the position of the `.loadingContainer` will be adjusted to be at the center of the loading screen. If you just want it to disappear, then you can apply `display: none;` or `opacity: 0;`.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, @Benedek thanks for the solution, I tried the first code snippet you provided before but it will push the other content of the screen down when the loading element shows.

In the 2nd code snippet, the justify-content is not working with the position fixed, have seen some StackOverflow posts too, but didn't help. Any other approach?

Comment: Try removing the `position: fixed;` from the `.loadingContainer` as it's no longer needed and should solve the problem.